# Spring Boot/Spring Kafka SSL Configuration by environment variables impossible

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, environment-variables, spring-kafka

I have a spring boot application which communicates with Kafka.

I configure this application in production by injecting environment variables.

For kafka, I can configure most things with environment variables - bootstrap servers, ssl truststore location, ssl truststore password, group id, topic, eg:

```
SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE-LOCATION: "file:/opt/app/jks/totally_real_file.jks"
SPRING_KAFKA_SSL_TRUSTSTORE-PASSWORD: "hunter2"
```

Because I can configure ssl keystore and password with environment variables, I would assume that I could configure the SSL Protocol and Security Protocol; eg:

```
SPRING_KAFKA_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SSL"
SPRING_KAFKA_PROPERTIES_SSL_PROTOCOL: "SSL"
```

But, I would assume incorrectly, because when I set it there, a message appears:

```
The configuration 'SECURITY_PROTOCOL' was supplied but isn't a known config
The configuration 'SSL_PROTOCOL' was supplied but isn't a known config
```

More messages appear!

```
Bootstrap broker one:9093 disconnected
Bootstrap broker two:9093 disconnected
Bootstrap broker more_than_two:9093 disconnected
```

This makes me sad. I search the internet. 
I find links:

[Spring Kafka SSL setup in Spring boot application.yml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200107/spring-kafka-ssl-setup-in-spring-boot-application-yml)

This doesn't help much, I want to configure by environment variable...

I find github issues links (this is getting worse):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-kafka/issues/157

This gives a partial clue.

The yml:

```
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol: "SSL"
```

*should work*, but doesn't

The yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      security.protocol: "SSL"
      ssl.protocol: "SSL"
```

*DOES* work! but it is impossible to represent with environment variables.

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible for boot to consider every possible Kafka property. There are so many. Only a subset are supported as first class properties.

You can use system properties instead of environment variables.

**EDIT**

You can do it as follows:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      security.protocol: ${SEC_PROT}
```

Comment: By system properties, do you mean properties set in code or settings files bundled into the built artifact? If not, could you provide an example? I understand that there are too many settings to provide first class properties for, but this has to be one of the most common settings.

Comment: jvm arguments -Dfoo=bar

Comment: Is there an overview of the environment variables supported by Spring Boot for Kafka configuration?

Comment: Properties supported by boot directly (with content-assist in IDEs) are [documented in the boot reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties). All other arbitrary properties can be set via the `...properties` properties (global, admin, consumer, producer). See the update to my answer for how to use environment variables.

Comment: I appreciate the update Gary - and i think it points to the real problem I have in the architecture of my app. I don't think there's a "fix" to the problem I have, as written.

Comment: ? My edit provides a reasonable "fix" to the problem - you just can't express the variables directly; you need placeholders in the YAML. At least with that solution you can have different props between test and prod, which is what your desire is. There is no way boot can anticipate and/or keep up with additions to arbitrary Kafka properties.

Answer (score 1):

My workaround was to set the following in my application.yml:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      security.protocol: "SSL"
      ssl.protocol: "SSL"
```

I do not like this solution, as it requires me to build different artifacts for prod and SIT. (The fact that SIT Kafka does not have SSL enabled is a question for another day and another drink)

Comment: You can use environment variables within the YAML - see the update to my answer.

Comment: I believe `ssl.protocol` should not belong to `properties` but level above: `spring.kafka.ssl.protocol`

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the environment variable names aren't correct. For example, instead of this:

`SPRING_KAFKA_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL`

I think you want to use a producer/consumer-specific name like:

`SPRING_KAFKA_PRODUCER_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL`

or

`SPRING_KAFKA_CONSUMER_PROPERTIES_SECURITY_PROTOCOL`