# Kafka consumer code for 4 topics

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka

I want to write  kafka consumer code for 4 topics (topic1, topic2, topic3, topic4).
And I have 4 tables in my database (table1, table2, table3, table4).
So whatever data is there in topics should append in the respective tables.

Like:

```
topic1 data will be appended to table1
topic2 data will be appended to table2
topic3 data will be appended to table3
topic4 data will be appended to table4
```

Comment: what is the problem in making this?

Comment: i have written the code. But while running it gives error like: Could not login. the client is being asked for a password. And next day any how i solved this error. But again next time it started giving No ket to Store error. @Deadpool

Comment: and one more thing do i need to create 4 group id for 4 topics ? because in my recent code i have only one group id @Deadpool

Comment: do all topics will have same data? how do you differentiate data of each topic?

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: groupid is something to identify consumer belongs to this group, consumers of same group will not consume same message, try to read this https://www.confluent.io/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-the-new-apache-kafka-0-9-consumer-client/

Comment: In my param file i have passed 4 topic names : Topic1=A, Topic2=B, Topic3=C, Topic4=D   And every topic has different data in json format @Deadpool

Comment: scala and python @Alihosseinshahabi

Comment: val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
  "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092",
  "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
  "group.id" -> "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream",
  "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
  "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)


val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topic1, kafkaParams)
)

stream.map(k=>k.key)

Comment: why don't you update your code in question

Comment: As i mentioned above i am creating 4 different kafkautils.createstream for 4 topics by passing their names . So my question is do i need to create 4 kafkaparams for every topic or one kafkaparam will be enough @Deadpool

Comment: Why are you using Spark to consume?

Comment: if four topics are on same cluster and if you want to assign  four topics to same consumer, then one kafkaparam is sufficient

Comment: because its a spark streaming application @cricket_007

Comment: If you would like to send Kafka data into a database, my suggestion would be to use Kafka Connect

Comment: yes my 4 topics are on same cluster @Deadpool

Comment: I am new to kafka . i don't know about kafka connect @cricket_007

Comment: Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No key to store now i am getting this error while running code @Deadpool

Comment: and sometimes this error also : org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka consumer

Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Could not login: the client is being asked for a password, but the Kafka client code does not currently support obtaining a password from the user. not available to garner  authentication information from the user

Comment: you need ssl authentication for your kafka cluster i believe, check this if you need ssl configuration https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200107/spring-kafka-ssl-setup-in-spring-boot-application-yml/51201034#51201034

Comment: i have 4 topics say 
topic1=A
topic2=B
topic3=C
topic4=D

Topic1 data will be appended to TableA
Topic2 data will be appended to TableB
and similarly for others also

so based on the above reqwuirement i have to write a kafka consumer code. So can you plz help me to write this code because i have no clue how to do that as i am new to kafka @Deadpool

Comment: i have 4 topics say 
topic1=A
topic2=B
topic3=C
topic4=D

Topic1 data will be appended to TableA
Topic2 data will be appended to TableB
and similarly for others also

so based on the above reqwuirement i have to write a kafka consumer code. So can you plz help me to write this code because i have no clue how to do that as i am new to kafka @Alihosseinshahabi

Comment: I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration while running the kafka consumer code  @Deadpool

Comment: my kafka_jaas config is as follows: Client { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required doNotPrompt=false useTicketCache=true principal="hd01@AD.NET" useKeyTab=true serviceName="dazr_kafka" keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/hd01.keytab" storeKey=true client=true; }; KafkaClient { com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required doNotPrompt=false useTicketCache=true principal="hd01@AD.NET" useKeyTab=true serviceName="dazr_kafka" keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/hdtrvn01.keytab" storeKey=true client=true; }; @Deadpool

Comment: Why don't you update your code?

Answer (score 0):

As listed in the Spark Kafka documentation, you can provide an array of topics to subscribe to

```
val topics = Array("topicA", "topicB")
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
  streamingContext,
  PreferConsistent,
  Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
)
```

When using a regular Kafka Consumer, you can provide a regex pattern for your topics

From the comments, it sounds like your Kafka cluster is using authentication, which you must do [some additional Spark configuration for it to work](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#ssl--tls)

You mention a database, so instead of writing questionably tolerant Spark code yourself, it might make sense to look at [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html), which is part of your Kafka installation already

Comment: if i use Array of topics, then what about val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream. how will i use it for 4 topcs. because whatever data is coming from producer i have to append in every topic and also data is different for every topic

Comment: What about it? If you're sending String data (for example, JSON) into every topic, then the stream sees all the messages.

Comment: i have 4 topics say 
topic1=A
topic2=B
topic3=C
topic4=D

Topic1 data will be appended to TableA
Topic2 data will be appended to TableB
and similarly for others also

so based on the above reqwuirement i have to write a kafka consumer code. So can you plz help me to write this code because i have no clue how to do that as i am new to kafka

Comment: Unfortunately, Stackoverflow isn't a tutoring site. Plus, I don't know the Spark Kafka API all too  well, but I can tell you that I would suggest making 4 independent DirectStream objects that are able to write to your destination tables independently. That way, you're not trying to consume all four topics at once.

Comment: but while running the code i am facing authentication issues as mentioned in the comments. So i want to know how to overcome all these issues

Comment: I've linked to the the Spark Kafka SSL documentation for helping you solve that. I can't know your Kafka passwords because I didn't install it

Comment: I am getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration while running the kafka consumer code @cricket_007

Comment: my kafka_jaas config is as follows:  Client {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 doNotPrompt=false
 useTicketCache=true
 principal="hd01@AD.NET"
 useKeyTab=true
 serviceName="dazr_kafka"
 keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/hd01.keytab"
 storeKey=true
 client=true;
};
KafkaClient {
 com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
 doNotPrompt=false
 useTicketCache=true
 principal="hd01@AD.NET"
 useKeyTab=true
 serviceName="dazr_kafka"
 keyTab="/etc/security/keytabs/hdtrvn01.keytab"
 storeKey=true
 client=true;
};

Comment: I suggest you post a new question, with properly formatted code, rather than continue this in the comments because I've already answered "how to consume from multiple topics"... Regarding Hbase, Spark nor Kafka include any Hbase code, so I don't know why that error would happen