# Connecting my Kafka Consumer to a Schema registry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to connect a spring boot Kafka application to a schema registry to read messages, but I keep running into an issue.

my **application.yaml** looks like this

```yaml
spring:
  kafka:
    bootstrap-servers: //server_url:port
    client-id: //client_id
    consumer:
      ssl:
        key-password: //password
        key-store-password: //password
        key-store-location: //path to jks
        key-store-type: jks
        trust-store-password: //password
        trust-store-location: //path to jks
        trust-store-type: jks
      bootstrap-servers: //server_url:port
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      client-id: //client_id
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
    properties:
      schema.registry.url: // https:schema_reg_url
      sasl.mechanism: PLAIN
      security.protocol: SSL
      ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm:
```

**Main class**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
public class AksKafkaConsumer {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AksKafkaConsumer.class, args);
  }
}
```

Then my **Kafka Listener service**

```java
@Service
public class listenerService {
  @KafkaListener(topics = "topic_name", groupId = "group_id")
  public void consumer(GenericRecord record) {
    System.out.println(record);
  }
}
```

while running this, I'm always getting an error as follows

```
ERROR o.s.klistener.LoggingErrorHandler.handle - Error while processing null
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition [---] at offset 700501. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error retreiving Avro schema for id 1234
Caused by: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exception.RestClientException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, oject, 'true', 'false', or 'null')
at[source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpUrlConnection$HttpInputStream): line 1, column 2]; error code 50005
.......
```

I know there's nothing wrong with the topic messages, because I can view it & even consume it through another application.

any thing I'm doing wrong that's causing me not reading the message? is it a schema registry connection problem???

the KafkaListener method is working for consuming String messages, but I need to consume a GenericRecord.

any suggestions?

**EDIT** -
I can connect in a different way as a POC, but it doesn't really serve my purposes. This is how...
**Main Class**

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
public class AksKafkaConsumer {
  public void main (String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext appContxt = SpringApplication.run(AksKafkaConsumer.class, args);
    KafkaConsumerService service = appContxt.getBean(AksKafkaConsumer.class);
    service.consumMsg(args);
  }

  @Service
  class KafkaConsumerService {
    public void consumMsg(String[] args) {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      ......
      props.put(ProducreConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "bootstrap_config");
      props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "schema_registry_url");
      props.put(CONSUMER_CONFIG.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
      props.put(CONSUMER_CONFIG.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
      //this goes on to manually setup 12 other property
      .....

      KafkaConsumer<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> consumer = null

      try {
        ArrayList<String> topics = new ArrayList<String>();
        topics.add("topic_name");
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<GenericRecord, GenericRecord>(props);
        consumer.subscribe(topics);

        while(true) {
          ConsumerRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> records = consumer.poll(1000);
          for (ConsumerRecord<GenericRecord, GenericRecord> record : records) {
           System.out.println(record);  
         }
        }
        catch (Exception e) { ... }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Manually adding all the configurations like that, is causing all sort of problems, especially with pulling the key/trust store jks files..... plus while running from an IDE I need to also set System.setProperty() too.

Also, I don't like exposing the jks file path & passwords from the main class like that.

I'm okay with building a separate configuration class for it, I'm just not sure I know how to configure something like that (w/ schema registry).

**ANY** help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: The error is saying that the address you provided is returning html, not JSON

Comment: right, which means I'm not connected to the schema somehow, and something is wrong with the configurations.. a. ny idea what exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure your ssl properties are all correct. The Kafka properties themselves have periods, not hyphens https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200107/spring-kafka-ssl-setup-in-spring-boot-application-yml